# How to create 3D website like this? (babylon.js or KRpano?)

Tags: vue.js, nginx, babylonjs, krpano

I've seen this website [https://greenewera.com.tw/2023/](https://stackoverflow.com) and curious about how to make it.

Already checked with wappalyzer and it shows the framework like Vue.js and Ngins as web server, but how to create the 3D effect and the control panel like the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using the 3D library [Baylon.JS at https://www.babylonjs.com/](https://www.babylonjs.com/). It's a great library I have used many times in the past and I am still using for new projects.

From there site:

> Our mission is to build one of the most powerful, beautiful, simple, and open web rendering engines in the world, and we are excited to announce the next step forward in that journey: the release of Babylon.js 6.0. This new version brings a smorgasbord of performance improvements, rendering enhancements, and exciting new features that you will NOT want to miss.